# How to create/update a linked document in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have 2 linked documents and I need to update one of them

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  has_one :resume
end

class Resume
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title
  belongs_to :user
end

#...............

new_resume = Resume.new({:title => "my title"})
if current_user.resume && current_user.resume.any? #if resume exists then update it
  current_user.resume.update_attribute(:resume, new_resume)
else #otherwise create it
  current_user.resume.create(:resume, new_resume)
```

It's not working because in the second case `current_user.resume == nil`.

How do `update/create` `Resume` for current user?

Comment: pass the hash directly instead of mongo-object i.e something like this `current_user.resume.create({:title => "mytitle"})`

Comment: current_user.resume is nil, thus it will throw an exception.

Comment: sorry Grienders it `has_one` hence the syntax would be different try this `create_resume` i.e `current_user.create_resume({:title => "mytitle})`

Comment: Hmm, does the method .create_resume exist?

Comment: it better to check in documentation that standard convention that even activerecord too follow and also mongoid for has_one association chain check over here for [mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_one) visit the last operation in table of `1-1` reference just above `1-n` you can check `activerecord` documentation on `1-1` relation ship since the method standard is taken from there

Comment: ...and it said me that there was no method named like create_resume.

Comment: are you sure you doing it the right way I do it all the time it work for me